# Bacteria counts in petri dish confusion

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, log-linear

I'm currently (attempting) to help a fellow student with some statistical analysis. Basically she is looking at the effect of a sugar treatment on bacterial growth within a petri dish.

She has three time points of interest and for each time point she has three petri dishes. Within each petri dish, she places two drops of the same material on opposite sides. At the end of the time period, she counted the colonies remaining within each drop within each petri dish. I'm not a biologist so I'm not 100% sure if this was the exact experimental design but basically:

- The response is the count of bacterial colonies.
- Explanatory variables include time to collection (3 levels) and treatment (control vs sugar).

Anyways, I thought that this would be a pretty straight forward analysis via a log linear model. Now I'm unclear about how to treat this two samples per petri dish situation. I'm thinking we should be looking at a GLMM and treating this as nesting (droplet within petri dish) but I'm not entirely sure -- the petri dishes should all be very similar prior to application of the treatments so its not really a random effect per say. Is it as simple as adding up the total count for the dish and using that? Perhaps also a contingency table of some sort? Grateful for any guidance!

Comment: I'm a bit confuse, what are you / is she trying to answer? Are the three time points "different", i.e., do they have different biological properties or are they just repetitions of the same experiment? Does the place the drops in all the dishes? If so, what is the control group?

Comment: You have too few data points for any sort of complex modelling! Can you plot the data?